# How can I check if object isn't deallocated on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, object, memory-management

How can I check if object isn't deallocated on Objective-C?

The following standard condition checks only if object is initialized:

```
NSObject *objectVariable = nil;
...
if (objectVariable) {...}
```

Comment: Do you plan on doing this in code, or at debugging time? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Do you want to check if it is released or deallocated? Huge difference. BTW - with proper memory management, there should be no need to do such a check. Better explain why you need this.

Comment: You are right, I mean deallocated. To fix crash for a few users.

Comment: You shouldn't "check" whether or not an object is deallocated. If some part of the code requires an object to live for a certain duration, it should ensure that by maintaining a strong reference to the object. In manual retain-release code, that means it should retain it until it's done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check after-the-fact whether an object is already deallocated or not, because it is invalid to do anything with an object that is deallocated (once an object is deallocated, any pointer that used to point to it is now an invalid pointer, and dereferencing it is undefined behavior). And since you don't know whether it is deallocated or not, and it may be deallocated, you cannot meaningfully examine it in any way. And a deallocated object may well "look like" a valid object if you try to examine it (it is undefined behavior, so any behavior is possible).

If this is an object of your own class, the obvious thing would be to print something or perform some other indicator action in the class's `-dealloc` method. That will tell you when it is deallocated.

Even if this is an object that is not of your own class, you may be able to either 1) add `-dealloc` as a category method, if the class doesn't override `-dealloc`, or 2) swizzle the `-dealloc` method, if the class does override it. Then you can print something in your version.

You can also profile it in Instruments; the Allocations instrument can tell you how many objects of a given class have been allocated, and how many are alive. If you suspect that you are losing track of objects or there is a retain cycle, the Leaks instrument may be able to tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with the comments, If you're doing memory management right, there should be no need for such a check. Nor am I aware of such a check, if the address gets populated with a new object, the check would pass but could still crash your app.

My suggestions are to:

1. Read up on manual memory management rules, pay special attention to how blocks affect memory management, alloc/init methods, when to use assign, etc. Memory management rules should become second nature to you. Start with [this Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).
2. Run static analysis on your app and fix any memory errors. Fix all the errors really, these are bugs in your app. (`CMD+Shift+B` or `Product->Analyze` in the menu)
3. Reproduce the crash in Instruments using zombies. Read the retain/release report to find out where the object may have been over-released. (`CMD+I` or `Product->Profile`. Select Zombies in the window that appears)
4. Consider converting to ARC. Converting to ARC doesn't get you completely off the hook for understanding ObjC memory management, but it will take a lot of the burden off of you.